# Как на мобильном сделать чтоб карту нельзя было двигать?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как на мобильном сделать чтоб карту нельзя было двигать? 
На десктопе так:
map.behaviors.disable('ruler');
map.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');

Comment: Попробуйте map.behaviors.disable('Drag');  Судя по описанию, то что нужно https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/behavior.Drag-docpage/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Непонятно как это у вас работает:
`map.behaviors.disable('ruler');` - это отключает линейку.   `map.behaviors.disable('scrollZoom');` - это отключает зумирование карты.

Вам нужно:
`map.behaviors.disable('drag');` - это отключает драг карты одним пальцем.
`map.behaviors.disable('multiTouch');` - это отключает драг карты или масштабирование карты мультисенсорным управлением (например, на сенсорном экране).

Comment: на настольном пк работает когда мышкой "тащиш")

Comment: multiTouch - то что нужно.